# How to switch back and forth between 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC based machine?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, 64-bit, 32-bit

We have some users on 64-bit Excel and some on 32-bit Excel.

We have Excel files which use 32-bit ODBC to grab data. It is difficult to migrate all users to 64-bit Excel.

Is there a mechanism within VBA to have a macro change which ODBC connection is to be used for the data?

Comment: You can look at precompilers???

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants

Comment: Thanks; the use of the compiler constant Win64 will is definitely helpful.

The harder question for me is how to choose DSN once I have that info, though.